# JSON Compression in Scala

Tags: json, scala, compression

JSON compression using serialise and deserialise does work. But the storing and reloading of the compressed json is not working.

After storing the compressed JSON in text file. The next application loads that file and tries to deserielise it. The next application loads the file and reads in line-by-line as text, how do i convert the text to byteArray so that I can deserielise it back to JSON

If I serielise a string and take the result and deserielise it, it works. the minute i write the serielse/compressed json to file and reload it into a string variable and then try to deserielse it, it does not work.

I know the problem lies in storing and reloading the compressed JSON

```
def serialise(value: Any): Array[Byte] = {
    val stream: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)
    oos.writeObject(value)
    oos.close()
    stream.toByteArray
  }

  def deserialise(bytes: Array[Byte]): Any = {
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
    val value = ois.readObject
    ois.close()
    value
  }
```

// WORKS (Below)

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val json_msg_string = "{\"data_type\":\"input\"}
   val s_result: Array[Byte] = serialise(json_msg_string)
   val d_result = deserialise(s_result)
}
```

// Does NOT work (Below)

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val json_msg_string = "{\"data_type\":\"input\"}
   val s_result: Array[Byte] = serialise(json_msg_string)

   // write to file
   new PrintWriter("/home//test_json_compressed.txt") { write(s_result.toString); close }

   // reload file
   for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
      deserialise(line)
    }
}
```

1. What is the best and fastest way to compress JSON (Scala)
2. How do I store the compressed JSON (Scala)
3. How do I reload the compressed JSON and convert it back to JSON (Scala)

Comment: Deserializing the file line by line would not necessarily give you valid json, best read whole file and then deserialize it. Also best add some debugging output...

Comment: Did you give that a try?